# Current and voltage distribution on a beverage and on a rhombic antenna?

Tags: antenna

Afternoon.

I've been learning about antennas a lot lately, and right now i'm reading about both of these, been trying to find a read about their voltage and current distribution but so far i haven't found anything.

Care to tell me how it's on both of them with a little short explanation? I'm kinda new to this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The key concept with [traveling-wave antennas](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/160969/11683) is that there are no standing waves, which means that the current and voltage levels are the same everywhere along the antenna conductors.